# Scaling full width video background rows with viewport

Tags: css, wordpress, video, viewport, scaling

I am not a developer, which I will make painfully clear here:

There are 3 full screen video background elements towards the top of my company website’s homepage ([papertown.tv](https://www.papertown.tv) — see the rows titled, 'how it should be,’ ‘your value with replay value,’ and ‘simply, lasting results’), which I cannot for the life of me seem to coerce into scaling down with the viewport. In other words, instead of maintaining their full fields-of-view as the viewport shrinks, they get cropped by their respective rows. It’s to the point where it’s nearly impossible to tell what’s happening in the videos on mobile.

I tried this @media query but it just made the videos float around awkwardly inside the rows:

```
@media (max-width: 798px) {
#this-is-how-mobile .fl-bg-video,
#your-value-with-mobile .fl-bg-video,
#simply-lasting-results-mobile .fl-bg-video
    {
 height: 1920px;
 width: 1080px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(.45);
        transform-origin: 0% -27%;
        z-index:-1!important;
```

The site was built on WordPress with Beaver Builder (sorry). But this should be a simple fix, no?

Happy to send some Doge or Ether to whomever helps me solve this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The link isn't working, are you hosting the video or linking an iframe?

Comment: Link isn't working for me either.
I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the transformations but it is easier to deal with videos if you set `aspect-ratio: 16/9;` and now you can set the width or height (you can use `width:100%` to be as wide as the parent and with `aspect-ratio` it is proportioned) and it'll work predictably without needing to scale or transform it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the iframe with the following html/css and it will scale to fit the size of the container.

**CSS**

```
.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.video-wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="video-wrap">
      <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
      <iframe width="560" height="349" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/572629737?title=0&byline=0&muted=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&background=1&app_id=122963" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```